# Is it possible to whitelist a page to not have CSRF applied to it with Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, csrf-protection

Looking at the docs for [CSRF security and Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) there does not appear to be a way to mark a particular form/url as not needing CSRF protection. I have a site where in general I want CSRF enabled however there is one public page which has one form which is something something that people are very likely to bookmark and get errors due to a stale CSRF header between server reboots. Is there some way I can disable the CSRF protection on just one form/URL?

**EDIT** I am using spring-security-web version 3.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: It just occured to me that perhaps there is a way to tell the browser not to cache the page at all? Is that a fix to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the[documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/)

> You can also specify a custom [RequestMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-csrf-request-matcher-ref) to determine which
>   requests are protected by CSRF (i.e. perhaps you don't care if log out
>   is exploited).